# Need advice on learning Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have recently got a call to work at Senior positions for big data technologies where spark is one of the go-to technologies they are planning to adopt. Ofcourse i want to learn it before i join them.

I have a desktop which has **8 Gigs of Ram and 2 cores**. I want to download pre-built VMs offered by **HDP** and **Cloudera** but clearly i am running short of resources as per their prescription.

Can you please suggest any way i can follow to learn few practice tests on spark and how can i get the required infrastructure for it.

Please help

Comment: It requires a subscription, but I have a pluralsight course that should get you up to speed pretty quick -> https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/apache-spark-fundamentals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please checkout bigdatauniversity.com

There are two **FREE** Spark Courses to get you started.

http://bigdatauniversity.com/courses/spark-fundamentals/

At the end of the course, you get 3 attempts to pass the certification test which will issue Open Badge for you.

On top of above, the labs in the course include instructions for container images which are smaller prints than actual VMs.
I hope it helps.

Thanks,
Charles.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding infrastructure, we can setup and run the spark programs locally. Create a maven project and add the following dependencies and the plugin. Instead of executing the jobs on the cluster, they execute on the local machine.
Provide the master config as local[K]. Runs the spark locally with K cores.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
                <useZincServer>true</useZincServer>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Scala and Spark dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

The sample project with the dependencies can be found [here](https://github.com/nagendra-avr/spark-examples)